# Rails custom generator groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I've written a custom Rails 3 generator that generates rspec tests for each one of the models in my app. I've also written one for generate rspec tests for routes. When I run

```
rails generate
```

I get the following output (this is a segment):

```
ModelSpec:
  model_spec

RouteSpecs:
  route_specs
```

Does anyone know of a way that I could get it to group those like so:

```
SpecGenerators:
  model_spec
  route_specs
```

The directory structure is:

- generators/
- generators/model_spec
- generators/route_specs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from examples of [rollbar](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem/blob/master/lib/generators/rollbar/rollbar_generator.rb), [kaminari:config](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/generators/kaminari/config_generator.rb) and [kaminari:views](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/generators/kaminari/views_generator.rb), I assume this is automagically derived from your module structure.

So I *guess* that if you structure your code like follows, you'll achieve what you want.

```
#in generators/spec_generators/model_spec_generator.rb
module SpecGenerators
  module Generators
    class ModelSpecGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase

#in generators/spec_generators/route_specs_generator.rb
module SpecGenerators
  module Generators
    class RouteSpecsGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
```

Comment: Thanks for the research! I ended up inheriting from Rails::Generators::Base. Do you happen to know the difference? It only seemed to work the way I expected it when I inherited from Base.

Comment: Oh and it can't be a module for the generator, it's gotta be a class.

Comment: @musicnerd47 in fact I do not. But I'll make sure to look into it. Also, thanks for finding my module/class mix-up. Need to pay better attention.